# Using requests and BeautifulSoup to get Youtube video titles sometimes errors and sometimes works (Python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, youtube, python-requests, screen-scraping

I'm using requests and BeautifulSoup to attempt to get the title of a Youtube URL I give it. However, it only sometimes works. Sometimes it returns an error and other times it works; it's very inconsistent.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def video_title(url):
    req = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req, "html.parser")
    title = soup.find("span", class_="watch-title").text
    title = title.strip()
    return title

print(video_title(input("Enter video url: ")))
```

This code will sometimes return the title of a given video, others it'll return this message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sieea/OneDrive/Code & Electronics/Python/temp.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(video_title("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrV90gXmOpA"))
  File "C:/Users/sieea/OneDrive/Code & Electronics/Python/temp.py", line 7, in video_title
    title = soup.find("span", class_="watch-title").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Why does it only error sometimes and how can I make it consistently work?

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify different `User-Agent` - in this case I use user agent string from Google Bot. In my testing, with using this header I haven't been able to reproduce the exception:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbs7FT7dXYc'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'}

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, "html.parser")

title = soup.find("span", class_="watch-title").text
title = title.strip()
print(title)
```

Prints:

```
Videos for Cats to Watch - 8 Hour Bird Bonanza
```